# How can I round the value to 1 decimal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of radio buttons in different fieldsets.
I'm able to get the value of the radio buttons and divide that number however I'm not sure how to round it.

I would like to round the value of Total Score to one decimal.

HTML

```
<fieldset>
  <input class="calc" type="radio" id="star15" name="rating2" value="5" /><label for="star15">5 stars</label>
  <input class="calc" type="radio" id="star14" name="rating2" value="4" /><label for="star14" class="m-r-48">4 stars</label>
  <input class="calc" type="radio" id="star13" name="rating2" value="3" /><label for="star13" class="m-r-48">3 stars</label>
  <input class="calc" type="radio" id="star12" name="rating2" value="2" /><label for="star12" class="m-r-48">2 stars</label>
  <input class="calc" type="radio" id="star11" name="rating2" value="1" /><label for="star11" class="m-r-48">1 star</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <input class="calc" type="radio" id="star20" name="rating3" value="5" /><label for="star20">5 stars</label>
  <input class="calc" type="radio" id="star19" name="rating3" value="4" /><label for="star19" class="m-r-48">4 stars</label>
  <input class="calc" type="radio" id="star18" name="rating3" value="3" /><label for="star18" class="m-r-48">3 stars</label>
  <input class="calc" type="radio" id="star17" name="rating3" value="2" /><label for="star17" class="m-r-48">2 stars</label>
  <input class="calc" type="radio" id="star16" name="rating3" value="1" /><label for="star16" class="m-r-48">1 star</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <input class="calc" type="radio" id="star25" name="rating4" value="5" /><label for="star25">5 stars</label>
  <input class="calc" type="radio" id="star24" name="rating4" value="4" /><label for="star24" class="m-r-48">4 stars</label>
  <input class="calc" type="radio" id="star23" name="rating4" value="3" /><label for="star23" class="m-r-48">3 stars</label>
  <input class="calc" type="radio" id="star22" name="rating4" value="2" /><label for="star22" class="m-r-48">2 stars</label>
  <input class="calc" type="radio" id="star21" name="rating4" value="1" /><label for="star21" class="m-r-48">1 star</label>
</fieldset>

Total Score:
<input type="text" name="sum" />
```

JS

```
function calcscore(){
    var score = 0;
    $(".calc:checked").each(function(){
        score+=parseInt($(this).val(),10);
    });
    $("input[name=sum]").val(score / 8)
}
$().ready(function(){
    $(".calc").change(function(){
        calcscore()
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b4y7adg3/1/

Comment: have you researched about `.toFixed(1)` ?

Comment: As @CalvinNunes says, you can use tofixed like this `$("input[name=sum]").val((score / 8).toFixed(1))` <-- taken from your code.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can round the value multiplied by 10, then divide by 10:

```
var value = Math.round(number / 8 * 10) / 10;
```

See [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2jcLzm71/)

You can alternatively use `.toFixed(1)`; however, this will force a decimal, so that a value of `6`, for example, becomes `6.0`.

Comment: Thanks! I used the first example and worked perfectly!

Comment: You can use `Number.isInteger(n) ? n : n.toFixed(1)` to address that issue.